# Regular Expression for multiple specific-domain email addresses (separated)

Tags: regex, email, expresso

Good day,

I'm looking for a regular expression that would validate the following email addresses:

**a@domain.com, b@domain.com**

So far, I have this:

```
^([\w+-.%]+@domain\.com,?\s*)+$
```

It should not return anything in case of:

```
a@domain.comb@domain.com     or

a@domain.com b@domain.com
```

1. It should also return a result if a **;** is entered.
2. Also, is there a way to ensure a result will be returned only when
   there is a single **@** in an address?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean this `^[^@]+@domain\.com,?\s*$` ?

Comment: Here is some more information: I'm using Expresso to test my regex.  I need the regex to return only one result, being **a@domain.com, b@domain.com**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is `^(?>\b[\w+-.%]+@domain\.com(?:[,;]\s*)?)+\b$`.

I am using [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) with `(?>...)` so that no backreferences are created.

Result is as you request: `a@domain.com, b@domain.com`

Also tested with Expresso.

Comment: Your regex works great, except for the fact that when the input is **a@domain.comb@domain.com**, the regex still returns a result when it should not.

Comment: Please try with `^(?>\b[\w+-.%]+@domain\.com(?:[,;]\s*)?)+\b$`.